# How to use Twitter Bootstrap themes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i would like to use bootstrap themes inside some websites that i am developing, however after looking at the documentation and searching online i have found it somewhat troubling that there is no explicit how to guide start to finish with using bootstrap themes, [like found here](http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/). Furthermore i would like to download multiple themes into my project directory, extract them into the appropriate folders e.g. (css,img,js,ect...) and utilize them inside of my html files like so:

```
<div class="customized-bootstrap-item">myItem</div>
```

I am having a bit of trouble trying to do this because it seems there is no universality among the themes(e.g. each one may vary in how they work) and i don't want to hack together some dirty code if there is a proper way of doing it. So my question is , is there a proper way of adding themes into your existing project purely for aesthetics and customizing them by exchanging the appearance between one them and other themes, and if so how? 
Can you guys point me towards some tutorials? I need to know more about how linking these js and css files will affect other aspects of the themes, and how the html tags can be used properly in a uniform way across many themes, as i won't settle likely on just one theme.

edit:

After trying some of the suggestions i managed to figure out at least some of the problems i was having by including the css style of the specific theme that i want to use as a stylesheet link in the head section of the html page that i want to apply it to, which seems pretty straight forward anyway. However i'm still a little bit perplexed on how to get all of those cool elements that i see in the themes, especially the dashboard themes into my custom html page. A good example of a theme that i am looking at is [found here](http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/). If you guys could give me a bit of insight on how to get those elements on the page (i.e. dashboards, panels, UI elements etc...) that would be great. I may be mistaken but i don't think they are normal bootstrap classes, although i'm fairly new to bootstrap so i'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: tutorials? the easier way is just add the css of the theme to your project. that is a clean solution, have a look at this themes, they are clear and you only need to add that css to your project http://bootswatch.com/

Comment: @bto.rdz Just one css theme because i looked at the index.html page of some of the themes and they have multiple css and js links in there. Also what if i want to use multiple themes in one, do i need to include the css for each theme that i want to include?

Answer (score 1):

The definitions for all of these classes are located in a .css file, likely called 'bootstrap.css'. In the html page where you want to use bootstrap, add 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[PATH_TO_CSS_FOLDER_CONTAINING_BOOTSTRAP]/bootstrap.css" />`inside your . This will import all of bootstrap's css. If you need to use other themes, simply add that .css file into whatever folder has your css, then link to it in an html page.

Comment: Thanks i will try this out, i figured something like this but wanted to ask around to make sure. I'm still fairly new to bootstrap and i didn't want to start learning it the wrong way.

Comment: is the theme css file named bootstrap-theme.min.css ?

Comment: Sounds right. (but you should try before asking if you want to learn!)

Answer (score 1):

This is a great resource you can use to generate a theme http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/ then linking this to your existing site is quite easy: you simply include the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[PATH_TO_CSS_FOLDER_CONTAINING_BOOTSTRAP]/bootstrap.css" />` line in your code.

If you have downloaded from lavish it will include `lavish-bootstrap.css`. Don't forget to include `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` or the dropdowns *etc.* will not be functional.